# ASUS N550JV Internal Speakers are not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, asus, speakers

The internal speakers are not working. However the headphones are working. There is no problem with the speakers as they work perfectly fine in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dual boot n550jv with Realtek ALC668. try to deactivate audio device on windows and after restart on ubuntu your audio will work.